# Is there a builtin way of filling up values in the Model from cookies?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Let's say I currently have a `Controller` with the following `Action`:

```
    public ActionResult Index() {

        return View();
    }
```

I'd like to know if instead of this, I could have something like

```
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model) {

        return View();
    }
```

where the model is in some way already filled up with data stored in the cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. It would have to be a [HttpPost] action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
 ...
 ...
 ...
}
```

As far as I know, `[HttpGet]`, which is the default if you don't specify an attribute, can only take simple value types.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
     MyModel model = dataLayer.getModel(id);
     return View(model);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom model binder which will fill the view model from cookies:

```
public class MyModelCookiesModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var cookie = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["someCookie"];
        MyModel myModel = GetModelFromCookie(cookie);
        return myModel;
    }

    private MyModel GetModelFromCookie(HttpCookie cookie)
    {
        // TODO:
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

then register it in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyModel), new MyModelCookiesModelBinder());
```

and finally you could have:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model) 
{
    return View();
}
```

where the model will be populated from the cookie.

Comment: That seems interesting, yet that is basically having to do it for myself. What I was looking for was something like what you get with HttpPost, where it fills it for you "for free".